# Error: MongoD versions greater than 4.2.0+ must be enterprise build to enable backup

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB Ops Manager backup setup issue.

I have the MongoDB ops manager 4.4.12.100 and MongoDB enterprise 4.4.
I am trying to set up the backup for my MongoDB (MongoDB enterprise 4.4) during the final step i am seeing below error

"MongoD versions greater than 4.2.0+ must be enterprise build to enable backup"

Attached the screenshot also.

I am using MongoDB enterprise version but still throwing this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSJoo.png)

Comment: How do you know your mongod is an enterprise one?

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for your question.  I cross verified the MongoDB built module. it is not an enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

I have crossed verified the built module using the command
db.serverBuildInfo().modules

It was return blank [] . I just have to ensure whether your mongodb built to enterprise or not.